# how to populate array of objects in mongoose that reference to another schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

hello i went to populate all author with Course.

```
 const courses = await Course.find().populate('author','name -_id');
    console.log(courses);

const Author = mongoose.model('Author',mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    bio:String,
    website:String
}));

const Course = mongoose.model('Course',mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    author:[{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'Author'
    }]
}));
```

this is what i get:

```
[ { author: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    _id: 5cdc596bfd5a1e33e4833b2b,
    name: 'nodejs course',
    __v: 1 } ]
```

but i went to populate author name inside the author array 
like this `[{author:[{name:'jhon'},{name:'jhon2'}],`

```
[ { author: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    _id: 5cdc596bfd5a1e33e4833b2b,
    name: 'nodejs course',
    __v: 1 } ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should work for you:

```
const courses = await Course
            .find({})
            .populate('author')
            .exec();

console.log(courses);
```

Comment: not work [ { author: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    _id: 5cdc596bfd5a1e33e4833b2b,
    name: 'nodejs course',
    __v: 1 } ]

Comment: I believe you have all you need there. Try to do `console.log(JSON.stringify(courses));` instead.